# Can't install pycurl==7.19.0 on ubuntu 16.04 python 2.7.12

Tags: python, pycurl

Ubuntu - 16.04
Python - 2.7.12

Hi guys, I'm trying install pycurl==7.19.0 from setup.py, but catch this stack trace:

```
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/73/abcfbbb6e1dd7087fa53042c301c056c11264e8a737a4688f834162d731e/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz#md5=074cd44079bb68697f5d8751102b384b
Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-F8gcvD/pycurl-7.19.0/setup.cfg
Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-F8gcvD/pycurl-7.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-8sbXeG
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.47.0)
src/pycurl.c: In function ‘multi_socket_callback’:
src/pycurl.c:2351:9: warning: variable ‘ret’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int ret;
         ^
src/pycurl.c: In function ‘initpycurl’:
src/pycurl.c:3453:31: warning: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
     insstr(d, "COMPILE_DATE", __DATE__ " " __TIME__);
                               ^
src/pycurl.c:3453:44: warning: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Wdate-time]
     insstr(d, "COMPILE_DATE", __DATE__ " " __TIME__);
                                            ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lk5crypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcom_err
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone known what's wrong?

Comment: I tried it, not helped

Comment: @Bhargav The duplicate target question is way too broad and just a hodgepodge of random answers without a clear, definitive answer to fix this problem. I think it's a poor duplicate.

Comment: @cpburnz I've reopened. True, It is a mixture of answers (The libcurl answer is 10th down). If you do find time, try to cleanse that post.

Comment: Unless you're really just trying to use curl, I'd use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, i tried everything, i think that i had problem with pip install, i usually use sudo pip install.... so maybe some libraries don't have permissions to read. I restored snapshot with empty ubuntu and install all libraries again, without 'SUDO' pip install, thanx a lot for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lk5crypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcom_err
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap
```

Mean the libraries `idn`, `rtmp`, `gssapi_krb5`, `krb5`, `k5crypto`, `com_err`, `lber`, and `ldap` could not be found which most likely means they are not installed. I checked the dependencies of `libcurl3` and it directly depends on `gssapi-krb5-2` (which depends on `krb5-3` and `k5crypto3`), `idn11`, `ldap`, `rtmp1`, `ssl1`.

So, installing `libcurl3` should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

After that's installed, try installing *pycurl* again.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`